# ExpandableListView with adapter that contain Parent and Child

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I tried ExpandableListView With some Detials like Tracking Number and location in ParentHeader and Customer name,address,contact numberr in child but while compiling my code it shows nothing, review my code and help with what i am missing in my code. my tried code below

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ParentAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expandableListView;
ArrayList<ListHeader> listDataHeader;
ArrayList<ListChild> listDataChild;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.exp_lst_view);
    listAdapter = new ParentAdapter(this,listDataHeader,listDataChild);
    ListData();
    expandableListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

}

private void ListData() {

    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<ListHeader>();
    listDataChild = new ArrayList<ListChild>();

    ListHeader listHeader = new ListHeader();
    listHeader.setLocation("CHENNAI");
    listHeader.setTrackingNumber("ID5239");
    listDataHeader.add(listHeader);

    ListChild listChild = new ListChild();
    listChild.setCustomer("CUSTOMER 1");
    listChild.setAddress("28/34 xxx APTT, ccc rd , dddd-0000009");
    listChild.setContactNumber("0987654321");
    listDataChild.add(listChild);
}}
```

Adapter :

```
public class ParentAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

private Context context;
private ArrayList<ListHeader> listDataHeader;
private ArrayList<ListChild> listDataChild;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public ParentAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListHeader> listDataHeader, ArrayList<ListChild> listDataChild) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this.listDataChild = listDataChild;
}


@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    ParentViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (v == null) {
        viewHolder = new ParentViewHolder();
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_header, null);
        viewHolder.txtTrackingNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_tracking_number);
        viewHolder.txtLocation = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_location);
        v.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ParentViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    return v;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    ChildViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (v == null) {
        viewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_header, null);
        viewHolder.txtCustomer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_customer);
        viewHolder.txtAddress = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_address);
        viewHolder.txtContactNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_contact_number);
        v.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ChildViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    return v;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

public class ParentViewHolder {
    private TextView txtTrackingNumber;
    private TextView txtLocation;
}

public class ChildViewHolder {
    private TextView txtCustomer;
    private TextView txtAddress;
    private TextView txtContactNumber;
}}
```